# Continuously differentiable function that is injective

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable function such that $g'(a) \neq 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, show that g is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exist $a \neq b$ such that $g(a)=g(b)$. Then use mean value theorem to find $c \in (a,b)$ such that $g'(c)=0$.

Comment: I think we don't need to use the mean value theorem. Since g(a)=g(b), we can use Rolle's theorem

Comment: @user43418: You are right; in fact, the two theorems are equivalent.

Comment: But I still don't know how to conclude

Comment: @user43418: You can conclude by contraposition, "if $g$ is not injective then $g'$ has a zero" is equivalent to "if $g'$ doesn't vanish then $g$ is injective".

Answer (score 0):

Due to mean value theorem,only differentiability of g is sufficient for g to be injective.

Comment: This is correct, but you could elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ has continuous derivative such that this derivative never vanishes, then the derivative is only either positive or negative, by IVT. It then follows that the function is strictly monotonic, and therefore injective.